# Connect to VM localhost virtual directory

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, localhost

I have an Ubuntu guest VM operating inside Windows 7 host (VirtualBox with Bridged Networking enabled). In my VM, instead of browsing to `http://localhost/somesite` I set up virtual directories in apache to point to `http://somesite`. This is fine for when I'm working within Ubuntu, but I need to try to connect to the site from my Windows 7 host. If I enter `10.0.0.5` in my browser address bar, I do indeed see the apache welcome page, but how can I browse to my Virtual Directory/Site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the Virtual Directory/Site feature, but if it is similar to the Virtual Hosts feature in WebSphere, setting up a hostname "somesite" with IP 10.0.0.5 in the Windows hosts file (default: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) should work.

The entry would just look like this:

```
10.0.0.5 somesite
```

Please note that you need Administrator rights to edit this file in Windows 7. Easiest solution might be to open Notepad with those rights (right click -> run as Administrator) and then open the file from that editor.

Basically you need to instruct your browser to use that hostname for the Host field in the HTTP request (that is sent to the IP after resolving the hostname anyway) like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: somesite
```

Comment: Are you referring to the hosts file on Ubuntu? I'm sure that Apache is unaware of what IP the machine is on gets handed out.
EDIT: just tried creating a new entry under `/etc/hosts` -> `10.0.0.5 somesite`, and still cannot connect to it from Win7 if I type in that IP address

Comment: No, I mean the hosts file on the Windows machine (therefore provided the default Windows hosts file location). If you just use the browser with the IP address, Apache won't know which (virtual) hostname to use, as the browser won't provide one.

Comment: facepalm....right, of course I knew that you meant the hosts file under Windows....let me give it a bash

Comment: ok, edited it, but think I may need to restart my PC for the changes to take effect

Comment: Editing the hosts file should not reed a restart - you can verify this by using `ping somesite` and checking the IP that gets pinged.

Comment: I get a response from 10.0.0.5, but still nothing. I should probable also mention that I have multiple sites set up this way under Ubuntu. My Ubuntu hosts file looks like this: `127.0.0.1 localhost testsite somesite new-drupal-site`

Comment: Nevermind, I quickly wrote a small php script that gives a list of links to all of my virtual sites, and then replaced the default `index.php` with it. So now if I browse to `10.0.0.5` I get my landing page, and I can click on any of my links and it does indeed redirect me. THANX A MILLION BennyB!

Comment: So when you access http://somesite in Ubuntu it works, but if you access http://somesite in Windows it does not?
You might debug this by connecting to the Apache using `telnet 10.0.0.5 80` and sending the HTTP request manually like this:
`GET / HTTP/1.1` <ENTER>
`Host: somesite`

Comment: oh, and in my win7 hosts file I just create an additional entry per virtual site that I have...a bit tedious but it works 100%

Answer (score 0):

I guess 10.0.0.5 is Ubuntu VM's IP address on the LAN. If you want to browse, you can use http://10.0.0.5/somesite. If you don't want to be using 10.0.0.5, AFAIK you need to redirect those requests using DNS (that is, translating *somesite* to 10.0.0.5).